# How to increase the refresh rate of directx 11?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have searched a lot over the internet to find a solution for this one, but I cant find any solution. For one of my project to work, I need to increase the refresh rate of directx 11 running on windows server 2012. All the solutions that I found are able to solve the same problem, but for directx 9 or lower. Can any one tell me that how can I increase the refresh rate of directx 11 on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Realy? that isn't possible? No one knows?

Comment: Any kind of registry solutions? like in previous version of directx

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off VSync, which will have the effect of decoupling your frame rate from your display device. Call Present(0,0) to see unlimited frame rates.

If you leave VSync turned on, you cannot Present frames any faster than your display device allows, likely 60hz. You're free to set your display device to whatever refresh rate you like, but that has nothing to do with DirectX 11. If you're using an LCD monitor it's likely only capable of 60hz.